# Swift UICollectionView header not appearing properly

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionreusableview

The headers of the UICollectionView are not appearing properly. I have added one UILabel to the headers and it should display the section number. When I debug the viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind everything look alright. I have looked at different tutorials about collectionView headers and i can not find the error in my code.   [image]

here is the entire code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var collectionView:UICollectionView!;

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let layout:UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout();
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 20, bottom: 20, right: 20);
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 60, height: 60);
        layout.headerReferenceSize = CGSize(width: CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds), height: 50);

        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout);


        collectionView.dataSource = self;
        collectionView.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell");
        collectionView.registerClass(UICollectionReusableView.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "header");
        collectionView.delegate = self;
        self.view.addSubview(collectionView);

    }

}

extension ViewController:UICollectionViewDataSource{
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5;
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
       return 10
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath);

        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor();

        return cell;
    }




    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

        let view = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind(kind, withReuseIdentifier: "header", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor();


        let label = UILabel(frame: view.frame);
        label.text = String(indexPath.section);
        label.font = UIFont(name: "helvetica", size: 40);
        label.textAlignment = .Center;
        view.addSubview(label);



        return view;

    }


}
```

Comment: This is not the source of your problem, but it is important: you are not grasping that `collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind` returns a _reusable_ view. That word is important. This view might be the same view that already was used for another header. If so, you do not want to add the label again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace the line

```
let label = UILabel(frame: view.frame);
```

with

```
let label = UILabel(frame: view.bounds);
```

Though you should note that you need to fix other issues with your code regarding reusing a supplementary view. I would recommend creating a subclass of `UICollectionReusableView` with a label inside instead of adding a new label manually from your data source.